# D3 Sunburst layers displayed

Tags: html, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to make a D3 sunburst (with drill down) diagram on my page. I've been using this as a reference: http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307

It's all working fine (less the labels being too big), but I want it to only show the next layer/ring down on initialization. So instead of being like:
[image: all layers are visible]

Where you can see all the layers- I would rather have my centre ring, with North America, South America,etc. only being displayed and the user then being able to click on one of those to drill down to see USA/Brazil/etc:

[image: so only one layer]

I am unable to find examples of this- does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if you want to make it the way you suggesting ...then its almost a drill down pie chart...something like this http://bl.ocks.org/marcbc/raw/3281521/

Comment: Yeah I was about to edit my post and add that very link. However it's rather important it looks the way the last diagram in my post looks (with the centre ring), where as the pie chart is compact and splits out on drill down.